# Android: как перегрузить Fragment?

Tags: android-fragment, android-offline, android, java

Здравствуйте!

Интересует такой вопрос: как в приложении ВК сделана перезагрузка фрагмента при отсутствии подключения к сети?

[image]

При нажатии на кнопку "Повторить попытку" происходит перегрузка фрагмента, но как фрагменту "offline_fragment" сообщить какой фрагмент был до него?

Comment: почему Вы думаете, что это перезапуск?
я делаю подобные вещи с помощью нескольких View и ничего не перезапускаю

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее как вы это делаете.
У меня сейчас это происходит так: в активити есть метод `isOnline()`, в зависимости от его значения создается либо фрагмент с контентом, либо оффлайн фрагмент. В оффлайн фрагменте кнопка, я вот не могу сообразить, что надо конкретно написать в обработчике этой кнопки, что бы "перегрузить" фрагмент который был до потери связи. Сейчас попробовал сделать следующее - в активити создал поле `lastFragment`, и если запускаемый фрагмент не `offline_fragment`, то пишу его в поле, а потом при нажатии кнопки запускаю фрагмент из этого поля.

Comment: есть интерфейс, в нем 2 метода: onResult() и onException(). при старте фрагмента выполняется функция, в которой идет запрос на сервер. если интернета нет, то вызовется метод интерфейса onException(). в нем выставляется видимой View с кнопкой повторить. при нажатии на кнопку снова выполнится функция, в которой идет запрос на сервер. если запрос прошел успешно, то в методе  onResult() показываем View с основным контентом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед тем как запустить фрагмент отсылаешь информацию о том кем он был вызван и при "Повторить попытку" запускаешь старый фрагмент